# colors are not updated when updating chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Since version 2.9.0+ colors are not updated when updating chart. Till version 2.8.0 this works. How to handle updates in 2.9.0+ version?

This is how I try to update my chart.
chart = the chart
d = the data from my get request

```js
function addBarData(chart, d) {
  var data = [];
  data.backgroundColor = [
    color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
    color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
    color(window.chartColors.green).alpha(0.5).rgbString()
  ];
  data.borderColor = [
    window.chartColors.red,
    window.chartColors.blue,
    window.chartColors.green
  ];
  data.borderWidth = 1;
  data.data = d.values;
  data.label = d.label;
  chart.data.datasets.push(data);
  chart.update();
}
```

My complete code:
https://jsfiddle.net/wge1bj80/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `data` is actually a `dataset` and must be defined as an object but not as an array. This problem can be solved by changing `var data = [];` to `var data = {};`.

```
function addBarData(chart, d) {
  var data = {};
  ...
}

function addPieData(chart, d) {
  var data = {};
  ...
}
```

Please have a look at your amended [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6k4exbf8/1/).